# frame rate in react-webcam

Tags: reactjs, webcam

Can we set the frame rate in react-webcam?
I am trying to work on a virtual try-on problem and use the react-webcam library to display the webcam input on the browser.

However, I would like to reduce the frame rate to avoid latency. Need help.

Answer (score 1):

You can set it like this -

```
   videoConstraints={{
            ...videoConstraints,
            frameRate: { ideal: 30, max: 60 },
   }}
```